# Transit visa for Kenyan passport holder

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, kenyan-citizens

Do I need a transit visa for Amsterdam for my route - Nairobi to Berlin. I am traveling from Nairobi to Berlin via Amsterdam. My flight is KLM.

Comment: Short answer: No! Both Amsterdam and Berlin are in the Schengen area, *one* visa for the Schengen area will cover the trip. You will go through immigration in Amsterdam and then land in Berlin without an additional passport check.

Comment: This question is actually answered here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area